# JavaScript - Prevent event.default on parent anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a basic mobile navigation dropdown menu that makes use of nested  tags to open the second (and third) level of the navigation. However because the  elements are nested in anchor tags, they also trigger the default anchor events. Is there any way to prevent the anchors default event when clicking on a child element of said anchor ?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="main-menu">
    <li>
        <a href="some-link.html">Some Link
            <span class="target"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="some-link.html">Some Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.html">Some Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="some-link.html">Some Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Example Javascript**

```
$('span.target').on('click', function(event) {

    $(event.target).parent().preventDefault();

    // Do somthing

});
```

Comment: try `event.stopImmediatePropagation()`

Comment: why are you using an achor tag if you don't want to use it? why not just use a div or another span and use js to achieve the behavior you want?

Comment: preventDefault is not part of DOM, it is part of the event. Sounds like you want https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code. When you click on the child on anchor it prevents default behaviour of the parent anchor element. I use core javascript here:

```js
var menuAnchor = document.querySelectorAll('.main-menu a');

for(var i = 0, len = menuAnchor.length; i < len; i++){
 menuAnchor[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if(event.target != this) event.preventDefault();
 });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly that would prevent the default action on anchors which i want, i just don't want it to fire when clicking on the child elements inside the anchor.

Comment: When you click on the child of anchor it prevents default (stop visiting the link). But when you click on the anchor (not child of anchor) it does not prevent default (visit the link).

Comment: Brilliant, worked like a charm. Thank you very much.

Comment: Welcome @FrederickM.Rogers :)

Answer (score 2):

You could stop the propagation of the event, and cancel it's default behavior. See this:

```js
$('span.target').on('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // the rest of your code here...
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, I add those 2 lines as part of my 'automatic' workflow, in case I'm binding to an anchor tag (a) and prevent the default behavior of navigating away from the page (that's preventDefault()), and stopPropagation to avoid the parent elements' bound events from being triggered.

Comment: note...doing one or other will work...and `return false` will also do both

Comment: I add those 2 lines as part of my 'automatic' workflow, in case I'm binding to an anchor tag (`a`) and prevent the default behavior of navigating away from the page (that's `preventDefault()`), and `stopPropagation` to avoid the parent elements' bound events from being triggered.

Comment: i may be mistaken but won't this simply prevent the event/handler i have attached to the <span> from bubbling up to the anchor?

Comment: you're right @FrederickM.Rogers, it will prevent bubbling

Comment: I may need to edit my question then, because what i am trying to do is prevent the anchors default action from firing when the <span> tag is clicked. Bun only when the <span> tag clicked so that the anchor will work as in intended. This may very well be impossible but i know for a fact that i can target both when clicking the <span> tag.